# How to fix zero brightness on lightdm login screen and other xfce power manager issues

Tags: power-management, apple, powerpc, xfce4-power-manager

My Apple PowerBook G4 running Ubuntu 16.04 powerpc with XFCE4 desktop is now booting into a completely dark screen where I can only just see to put in my password. Also when the room gets a bit dark, the keyboard illuminates (good) and the screen goes to zero brightness and has to be adjusted manually (less good). Any tips on how to improve the configuration of xfce power manager to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal solution but I installed GDM3 and gnome-power-manager and removed Lightdm and xfce4-power-manager. It is working fine so far...